# DHCP & DNS Question

Tags: dns, dhcp

On a Ubuntu Install with DHCP set to get IP Automatically, does Ubuntu also pull the DNS IP's from the DHCP Server, or does the OS User need to add DNS Manually?

We have a user complaining they are getting DNS IP: 192.168.10.1  which from other sites seems to have been a standard IP being asked about.

I told them to manually set the DNS's into Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: You and I might want to hop into chat to discuss this in depth, because in a default Ubuntu setup with DHCP used, it will get IPs for DNS from DHCP.  If it's getting a non-working IP for DNS that's an issue with the network that they're on, NOT Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic Networking question, not just an Ubuntu question.

If you use pure DHCP, then IP addresses for DNS servers are inherited via DHCP.  This can be overridden by setting DNS manually in network settings in Ubuntu or any system and overriding it, or in my case setting DNS settings at the `system-resolved` level to take effect REGARDLESS of network configuration (DHCP or otherwise).

Most systems using DHCP will assign IP addresses for DNS via DHCP as well.  And sometimes, the IP address of the router is the DNS server handling requests to other hostnames on the network as well as forwarding to another DNS server for Internet lookups.  When assigned an IP address of `192.168.10.1` for example, when their IP is also `192.168.10.[something]` then it's getting the IP address of the router as the DNS server for the network.  If it gets `8.8.8.8` then that's set by the DHCP.

I can show you twenty such examples of network configurations that use this type of setup for DNS, all Ubuntu.  And all obey the rules of DHCP and DNS in a default installation (when you start examining things like my computer's setup then it gets a LOT more complex because I have a lot of other things at play for my DNS)

Comment: No, this is specific to what does Ubuntu do...   Some folks say DNS needs to be set manually....  I've seen times when the Linux code does not pull DNS, only pulls IP/SN/GW...  So no, not a generic question, a specific Ububtu question

Comment: @KBronze then that's configured wrong on a network level on those systems' networks.  Ubuntu in DHCP mode will always respect the IP addresses received in DHCP **except** when a local configuration overrides it.  Local Ubuntu always uses `127.0.0.53` though as the stub resolver that points to a DHCP configured DNS server.  192.168.10.1 is an IP address for a router on a given network usually (for a 192.168.10.* range) and that in turn is a DHCP assigned IP address. Again, a generic Network issue, not an Ubuntu one.

Comment: So the question is:  If DHCP is turned on, why would Ubuntu Grab the GW IP:  192.168.10.1 and say it's the DNS Server when it's only the gateway. The DNS Servers are actually:  75.114.xx.xa  & 75.114.xx.xb.... provided by the ISP....  My thoughts "User Config Issue"

Comment: Where did the system get an IP address? From the DHCP server; that is, the router. Where would you expect it to get DNS nameservers, then? From the router. The 192.168.x.y address simply means that the Ubuntu system will use whatever DNS nameservers that the router passes through. Unless explicitely set otherwise, the router simply uses those passed through from the ISP. Both most routers and your Ubuntu system can be configured to use any other valid nameserver, if desired.